# debugging a fastcgi++ applocation

Tags: debugging, fastcgi++

I'm starting with fastcgi++ and I'm a little bit surprised I couldn't find any information how to debug and trace it. How it can be done? I mean that not IDE runs it but only apache (or other web-server) could start a process and handle it correctly.

Now I'm using Qt Creator on gentoo for writing and compiling and apache to view the results

Comment: you can use gdb, but I make 100% ajax sites with fastcgi++, so I never need to use it.  I just do the js `alert()` method lol

Comment: @Sulla only `alert()`? But what about internal runtime errors? Now I have some error with forming sql-query and I don't know how to catch it

Comment: the ole js `alert()` method where put `alert()`s all over your script to find the javascript problem with selective commenting out of code.  with c++, i only use the db as a high speed repository, almost a nosql solution.  writing `WHERE`ing the `PRIMARY` and only `auto-increment`, so I probably can't help you there.  are you using connector/c++?  you might want to ask a new question if you're stuck on a db issue.